# htaccess redirect to https browser differences

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting

i have the following in my .htaccess file to redirect http requests to https

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newco.local,^newco.dev
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

this redirects correctly in firefox but not chrome or safari. this is hosted on phpfog at http://newco.phpfogapp.com
the ssl terminates at the load balances so i had to use %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} to check for https. could this be causing any issues with other browsers? any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try the `%{HTTPS}` variable.

If the request is `HTTPS`, the variable =`on`, otherwise, it =`off`.

Example Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newco.local,^newco.dev
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Here is the full [Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: OP clearly stated that HTTPS ends at the load balancer, so all requests get on port 80 (normal HTTP) at apache, so `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` is not an option.